# Symfony Twig datatable

Tags: php, symfony, datatables, twig

I'm building a Product Information Manager (PIM). Trying to build this with the symfony framework. The problem I'm facing at the moment. I'm showing my product information with datatables with the twig file example below.

```
{% set title = 'Product List' %}
{% extends 'table.twig' %}

{% block h1_page_header %} Product List {% endblock %}
{% block panel_heading %} Product List {% endblock %}
{% block thead %}
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <td>Actions</td>
    </tr>
{% endblock %}
{% block tbody %}
    {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ product.id }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ product.name }}
            </td>
            <td>
                SKU
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path('app_product_getproduct', {'id': product.id}) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="{{ path('app_product_delete', {'id': product.id}) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

The problem I have now is that my database has now almost 60-70K. But my product/list/ page is not rendering due to the 70K product which I want to show in datatables. It works fine for few 2-4k Products but above this it does not render.

I did a research and found out that I can resolve my issue with server side processing. But the question I have is there a better solution / alternative to achieve my goal?

Comment: Use pagination with knp paginator

Comment: For large resulset, server side is the best approach

Comment: Server side is the best for long terms, you will have more and more products, and problems with growth.. once you fixed it with server side, you will never again have this problem..

Comment: Not sure what you guys are suggesting with "processing server side" though?

Comment: @DarkBee probably server side pagination with search etc

Comment: That would be the solution indeed,

Comment: @Albeis Thx, this was one of the solutions which I had. I am not using bootstrap with datatables. In this case, I have to create my own page :( and my front end skills are not the best :) I was searching for plugin/module which was plug and play but this is not the case I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Even if server-side processing will help, some navigators may struggle to render all those elements at once. From a user point of view, that not interesting nether. Nobody will ever scroll through all the 70k products. Users are lazy :)

You should implement pagination, search-bar and filters to render a easy readable short list.

If you like JS you can implement a more elegant solution, like an infinite scroll.